# Matplotlib coordinates tranformation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to understand this code snippet:

```
def add_inset(ax, rect, *args, **kwargs):
    box = ax.get_position()
    inax_position = ax.transAxes.transform(rect[0:2])
    infig_position = ax.figure.transFigure.inverted().transform(inax_position)
    new_rect = list(infig_position) + [box.width * rect[2], box.height * rect[3]]
    return fig.add_axes(new_rect, *args, **kwargs)
```

This code adds an inset to an existing figure. It looks like this:
[image]

The original code is from [this notebook file](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jakevdp/ProntoData/blob/master/BasicAnalysis.ipynb#Trips-Over-the-Year).

I don't understand why two coordinates transformation are needed:

```
inax_position = ax.transAxes.transform(rect[0:2])
infig_position = ax.figure.transFigure.inverted().transform(inax_position)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Explanation

In the method `add_inset(ax, rect)`, `rect` is a rectangle in axes coordinates. That makes sense because you often want to specify the location of the inset relavtive to the axes in which it lives.
However in order to later be able to create a new axes, the axes position needs to be known in figure coordinates, which can then be given to `fig.add_axes(figurecoordinates)`.
So what is needed is a coordinate transform from axes coordinates to figure coordinates. This is performed here in a two-step process:

1. Transform from axes coords to display coords using `transAxes`.
2. Transform from display coords to figure coords using the inverse of `transFigure`.

This two step procedure could be further condensed in a single transform like

```
mytrans = ax.transAxes + ax.figure.transFigure.inverted()
infig_position = mytrans.transform(rect[0:2])
```

It may be of interest to read the matplotlib [transformation tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) on how transformations work.

#### Alternatives

The above might not be the most obvious method to place an inset. Matplotlib provides some tools itself.  A convenient method is the `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator`. Below are two ways to use its `inset_axes` method when creating insets in axes coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator as il

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(4,4))
ax1.plot([1,2,3],[2.2,2,3])

# set the inset at upper left (loc=2) with width, height=0.5,0.4
axins = il.inset_axes(ax1, "50%", "40%", loc=2, borderpad=1)
axins.scatter([1,2,3],[3,2,3])

# set the inset at 0.2,0.5, with width, height=0.8,0.4 
#   in parent axes coordinates
axins2 = il.inset_axes(ax2, "100%", "100%", loc=3, borderpad=0,
    bbox_to_anchor=(0.2,0.5,0.7,0.4),bbox_transform=ax2.transAxes,)
axins2.scatter([1,2,3],[3,2,3])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can I summarize the logic behind as the following: adding an inset (A) into an existing axes (B) requires an new axes of A to be inserted into the figure (C). The inset's position is usually defined relative to B's coordinates, so for C to add A, we need to transform A's coordinates from B's space to display coordinates then back to C's coordinates. Am I correct?

Comment: A followup and probably a stupid question, why can't I transform from Axes coordinates to figure coordinated directly? Why is transforming from Axes to  display required in between?

Comment: That's not a stupid question. Matplotlib provides the `transData`, `transAxes` and `transFigure` transforms out of the box. A transform directly from axes to figure is not provided, but it can easily be generated from the two existing transforms. I have edited the answer with two lines on how that would look like.